# Calling another activity in android

Tags: android

I am working in android development, I am trying to call another activity (activity 2) when a button is clicked

here is the code of button which is to be clicked to call the second activity

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Button1" 
        android:onClick="button1_func" />
```

the code of activity calss for this button

```
public void button1_func()
    {
        Intent i=new Intent ("second_activity");
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

ad here is manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.application1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.application1.Secondactivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.second_activity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but my app crashes when I click the button whats the problem??

Comment: post the stacktrace along with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
 android:onClick="button1_func" />
```

So you need

```
 public void button1_func(View v) // change method signature
 {
    // do something
    Intent i=new Intent (this,Secondactivity.class);
    startActivity(i); 
 }
```

and remove the below for SecondActivity in manifest

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.second_activity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Read about Explicit and Implicit intents @

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
Intent i=new Intent (MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
```

in place of

```
Intent i=new Intent ("second_activity");
```